# How to get the value of a datetime_select field with javascript in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datetime, forms, onchange

I had a previous question that touched this topic ([Rails: how to get value from another field when executing an onchange remote function in textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131694/rails-how-to-get-value-from-another-field-when-executing-an-onchange-remote-func)), but then I dugg a little deeper and realized that my problem is the datetime_select method.

I have a textfield with onchange. In the onchange I need to get the value of a datetime_select field to pass as a parameter when making the ajax call to my controller. The first thing to note is that a datetime_select is actually composed of five dropdowns (year, month, day, hour and minute), so I need to get the values of each of them separately (I presume, is there a simpler way?). But when I try to get their value with code like:

```
$(model + '_' + attribute + '_3i').value
```

which should return the value of the "day" dropdown I get an error: "TypeError: $("model_attribute_3i").value.toS is not a function"

If I create all the dropdowns for the datetime objects manually the same call works just fine. So there seems to be some magic in the way a datetime_select is composed that prevents me from asking the value of the dropdowns. Is there any way to go around this or do I just have to recode the datetime_select functionality in my application?

Comment: can we have some code for context. but off the bat it looks like your concat isnt replacing the variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be solved for now, problem was me being a javascript n00b... apparently I used same variable names in too many places which leaded to weird behavior.